# Cleaning Up (or Avoiding) Extra Whitespace with PyPDF2

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, pypdf

I've been extracting text from PDFs using PyPDF2. However it seems to be inputting erroneous white space in between words. Does anyone know of way to avoid this, or clean it after the fact? Here is an example:

> 'IN THE MATTER OF  an application submitted by 1113 York Avenue Realty
>   Company,  L.L.C. and 60th Street Devel opment LLC pursuant to Sections
>   197-c and 201 of the New York  City Charter for an amendment of th e
>   Zoning Map, Section Nos. 8c and 8d:'

Here "development" is spelt "devel opment" and "the" is the spelt "th e". I'd like to correct this.

Here is [PDF](http://www1.nyc.gov/assets/planning/download/pdf/about/cpc/000198.pdf). The example text is from list item number 1, on the first page.

Comment: @wp78de No, this [one](http://www1.nyc.gov/assets/planning/download/pdf/about/cpc/000198.pdf). I'm looking at list item number 1, on page 1.

Comment: I also had problems with that file but got proper content with pdf2tag.

Comment: @wp78de any suggestions for OS X or Unix?

Comment: pdf2tag is modelled after [pdf2txt](https://github.com/euske/pdfminer/blob/master/tools/pdf2txt.py) from PDFMiner.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move from PyPDF2 to pypdf: https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/migration-1-to-2.html

We improved the text extraction a lot in 2022.

This is a simple text extraction example of using pypdf version 2.x:

```
from pypdf import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")
page = reader.pages[0]
print(page.extract_text())
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Did you actually read the answer?

Comment: I did. I gathered you are a developer of the package, which had advancements in 2022. That it’s likely fixed. It’s an answer, but a better answe would be how to migrate the code to pypdf.

Comment: Did you also look at the migration page? It's pretty massive. It's also the official documentation. You wouldn't expect people who have issues with python 2 and should migrate to python 3 copy the whole 2to3 docs. That just doesn't make sense.

Comment: In those cases, would it make sense to show a minimal example of the new library? (Open file, extract text, display extracted text).

Comment: I added a simple example.

Comment: Fine to me. The change is mostly self-documenting: there are deprecation messages with how to move in case there is a change necessary